# Run ts-node via cron job

Tags: node.js, linux, typescript, cron, npx

I use a script written in TypeScript in order to redetermine item statuses in my app. I usually run this line:

```
npx ts-node statuscheck.ts
```

I wanted this to run everyday at midnight, and for that I tried to schedule a cron job as below:

```
0 0 * * * npx ts-node statuscheck.ts
```

It doesn't really work, I believe because $PATH is different in cron. Does anyone know the correct way of scheduling this script preferrably with ts-node as in the orinal npx line?

Comment: You can specify "PATH=......." in the cron file itself.

Comment: You need to specify the path to the folder

Comment: I have updated to: ```PATH=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

30 20 * * * npx ts-node /root/app/server/src/scripts/statuscheck.ts > /root/app/logs/statuscheck.ts.log 2>&1```           The log now says the following: ```npx: installed 9 in 2.19s
Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
- /root/.npm/_npx/80229/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js
- /root/.npm/_npx/80229/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/repl.js
- /root/.npm/_npx/80229/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js```

Comment: I kind of didn't get it, because I have equalized my path to the terminal one... in which the command works just fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it figured out. It seems adding "cd" to the command completely resolved it. This is how my crontab looked like in the end, with no errors and no need to install anything:

```
PATH=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

0 0 * * * cd /root/app/server/ && npx ts-node ./src/scripts/statuscheck.ts > /root/app/logs/statuscheck.ts.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the path to the folder where your `ts` file.

```sh
0 0 * * * /path/to/the/folder/node_modules/.bin/ts-node statuscheck.ts
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work... the output log says: ```/bin/sh: 1: /root/app/server/src/scripts/npx: not found```... is there a way to have everything in PATH as I usually would in the terminal?

Comment: I had this issue and resolved it by supplying a full path to ts-node as follows in my ts file:
#!/usr/bin/env -S npx /usr/local/bin/ts-node -T

Answer (score 0):

I have updated to:

```
PATH=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

30 20 * * * npx ts-node /root/app/server/src/scripts/statuscheck.ts > /root/app/logs/statuscheck.ts.log 2>&1
```

```
The log now says the following:
```

```
 npx: installed 9 in 2.19s Cannot find module 'typescript' Require stack:

/root/.npm/_npx/80229/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js
/root/.npm/_npx/80229/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/repl.js
/root/.npm/_npx/80229/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js
```

I kind of didn't get it because Path now equals what I have in terminal...  and I'm not asked this in terminal...  It Just works with no issues...

Comment: You need to install the dev deps of the package